# Google Maps API is stuck in mobile mode

Tags: google-maps

I think Google Maps API has a different default zoom behavior for mobile and desktop. For desktop, you can zoom with your mouse scroll.  But if I do this in mobile mode, it says "Use ctrl + scroll to zoom the map".

When I use my site [JusticeMap.org](http://www.justicemap.org) on desktop Google Maps API acts like it is in mobile mode. I've tested this in Chrome, Firefox, and Opera on my desktop.  By contrast another site that I develop works fine (http://www.energyjustice.net/map/nationalmap). How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default zoom behavior is actually closer to the first site you linked. The default zoom behavior is that zoom and pan are prevented on page scroll (and shows the ctrl + scroll overlay). See the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/interaction)

You can tweak your zoom behavior by setting the `gestureHandling` to `greedy` if that's what you really need, similar to your second site. Example:

```
function initMap() {
        var locationRio = {lat: -22.915, lng: -43.197};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 13,
          center: locationRio,
          gestureHandling: 'greedy'
        });
```

But if that doesn't answer your question, it would be best if you could post a minimal, verifiable code example so we can isolate the case.